# Ruby: Accessing calling child class constants from parent class?

Tags: ruby, oop

In Ruby, how can I access the calling class's constants from a parent class?

```
Module Foo
  class Base
    def test()
      #how do I access calling class's constants here?
      #ex: CallingClass.SOME_CONST
    end
  end
end

class Bar < Foo::Base
  SOME_CONST = 'test'
end
```

Comment: Do you have a lot of other classes that subclass `Foo::Base` with their own, different constants? Is `test` the same for all subclasses except for the constant?

Comment: @jstim Yes to both. `test()` is a method all subclasses should inherit, but is dependent upon a constant that differs between each subclass.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to work - it forces constant lookup to scope into the current instance's class

```
module Foo
  class Base
    def test
      self.class::SOME_CONST
    end
  end
end

class Bar < Foo::Base
  SOME_CONST = 'test'
end

Bar.new.test # => 'test'
```

Comment: 100 lines into writing about the template and strategy patterns, I'm glad this is here.

Comment: @jstim - for what it's worth, I'd be interested in reading what you have to write.